# Endless clones of the process after compile script

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, executable

[How it looks at Task manger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8x0B.jpg)I try to make simple script for taking screenshot every 5 min and save it as separate files. While i try it in console it works perfect, but after making .exe with pyinstaller i have this problem. And it didn't work at all, any screenshots but endless copies of my exe file until my system crushes.

There is my code:-

```
import time
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import schedule
from datetime import datetime

def take_screenshot():
    print("Taking screenshot...")

    image_name = f"screenshot-{str(datetime.now())}"
    image_name = image_name.replace(":", "-")
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()

    filepathloc = f"{image_name}.png"

    screenshot.save(filepathloc)

    print("Screenshot taken...")

    return filepathloc

def main():
    schedule.every(600).seconds.do(take_screenshot)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new with Python and don't know what can i try

Comment: Maybe you need [hooks](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html) for one or more libraries you are using?

Comment: What do you mean by endless clones of the process? What is happening? Maybe it is an issue with `schedule` spawning additional copies of the script?

Comment: Just added a screenshot with fragment of my task manager after running .exe

Comment: I found the problem. It was something with pyscreenshot, replaced it with pyautogui and it's works as must.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was something with pyscreenshot, replaced it with pyautogui and it's works as must.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).